# Mysql Case - Count Fields thats fall in curtain hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to set up a report that has the following fields :

[image]

Pretty much need the report to show the date, the total records that fall with in that date (so I group by Date) and then on a per hour basis for a 12 hour work day (from 8AM - 8PM) I need to count when a records is present within those times. After some brain storming and brain farts I thought why not use a case. This is what I have tried :

```
 SELECT 
        DATE_FORMAT(signintime, '%b %d, %Y') Date, 
        COUNT(session_id) as Total,
        SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) > 08 AND HOUR(signintime) < 09 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '8AM-9PM',
        SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) > 09 AND HOUR(signintime) < 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '9AM-10AM',
        SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) > 10 AND HOUR(signintime) < 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '10AM-11AM',
        SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) > 11 AND HOUR(signintime) < 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '11AM-12PM',
        SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) > 12 AND HOUR(signintime) < 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '12PM-1PM',
        SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) > 13 AND HOUR(signintime) < 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '1PM-2PM',
        SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) > 14 AND HOUR(signintime) < 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '2PM-3PM',
        SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) > 15 AND HOUR(signintime) < 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '3PM-4PM',
        SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) > 16 AND HOUR(signintime) < 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '4PM-5PM',
        SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) > 17 AND HOUR(signintime) < 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '5PM-6PM',
        SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) > 18 AND HOUR(signintime) < 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '6PM-7PM',
        SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) > 19 AND HOUR(signintime) < 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '7PM-8PM'
 FROM session 
 WHERE session.status = '3'
 GROUP by HOUR(signintime), Date;
```

If you notice the picture above, the total is 1 for that entire day (Apr 19, 2013) now if you notice the times (8AM - 8PM) they are all zeroed out. I am unsure as to where to turn to / where to debug this. Hopefully with another set of eyes I can get this moving along.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not need to use both the `>` and `<` to get the result, you can just check the `hour` value:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(signintime, '%b %d, %Y') Date, 
  count(session_id) as Total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) = 08 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '8AM-9AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) = 09 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '9AM-10AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '10AM-11AM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '11AM-12PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '12PM-1PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '1PM-2PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '2PM-3PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '3PM-4PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '4PM-5PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '5PM-6PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) = 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '6PM-7PM',
  SUM(CASE WHEN HOUR(signintime) = 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '7PM-8PM'
from session
WHERE session.status = '3'
group by DATE_FORMAT(signintime, '%b %d, %Y');
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb9dc1/3)

Comment: This actually works bluefeet, but the problem is will this check to see if a row has a timestamp between the times though? I actually tried this but I thought this was a "glitch"

Comment: When will it have a time between?  If the timestamp is `08:59:59`, then it will be in the 8AM timeframe. The hour will always be equal to something.

Comment: +1 again you helped me! Thanks so much (again). I guess my logic is fudged up.